# If the gradient of a function is valued zero at a point, must it have a singularity at that point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am unsure of the relationship between a gradient vector and the surface itself. In this case, *F* is a continuously differentiable, real-valued function, and *p* is a point on the level set *M* where *F = c*.

In the case where *∇F(p) = 0*, is it true that M must have a singularity at *p*? Why?

Also, does this relationship work the other way? If *M* has a singularity at *p*, must the gradient *∇F(p)* have a value of zero?